# Extract a string from HTML with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

Here is the html...

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" 
src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F11111111&amp;auto_play=false
&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;color=c3000d&amp;show_comments=false&amp;liking=false
&amp;download=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;show_playcount=false"></iframe>
```

I'm using NodeJS. I'm trying to extract the trackID, in this case `11111111` following `tracks%2F`. What is the most stable method for performing this?

Should I use regex or some JS string method such as `substring()` or `match()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find tracks with node module [url + jsdom + qs]

Try this

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var url = require('url');
var qs = require('qs');

var str = '<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"'
  + 'src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F11111111&amp;auto_play=false"'
  + '&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;color=c3000d&amp;show_comments=false&amp;liking=false'
  + '&amp;download=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;show_playcount=false"></iframe>';

jsdom.env({
  html: str,
  scripts: [
    'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js'
  ],
  done: function(errors, window) {
    var $ = window.$;
    var src = $('iframe').attr('src');
    var aRes = qs.parse(decodeURIComponent(url.parse(src).query)).url.split('/');
    var track_id = aRes[aRes.length-1];

    console.log("track_id =", track_id);
  }
});
```

The result is:

> track_id = 11111111

Comment: Is this more stable than the other Regex answers? Sorry, I'm kind of newbie.

Comment: it's stable than regex because qs and url modules a made for that and it's tested.

Comment: If there are multiple iframes on the page, how do I loop through the html of each one(using a URL instead of raw html)? I'm only able to retrieve the first iframe html with your example.

Answer (score 2):

If you know `tracks%2F` is only going to show up once you could do:

```
var your_track_ID = src.split(/tracks%2F/)[1].split(/&amp/)[0];
```

There are probably better ways, but that should work fine for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

**Update for 2019...**

This builds off of blueiur's answer and walks through a solution in more detail. `JSDOM`needs to be installed before you can use it:

```
npm install jsdom
```

Now, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom), you can instantiate `JSDOM` like this:

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
```

You've already got some html you want to parse, I'll use your example and define it as a template literal:

```
const data = `<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" 
src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F11111111&amp;auto_play=false
&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;color=c3000d&amp;show_comments=false&amp;liking=false
&amp;download=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;show_playcount=false"></iframe>`;
```

Here's the fun part... parse the html in NodeJS:

```
const { document } = (new JSDOM(data)).window;
```

What's happening here? You're creating a new JSDOM object with the provided HTML and grabbing the `document` attribute of the `window` attribute. From this point on, you can use `document.getElementsByTagName()` and other similar functions just like you would in a browser.

To continue with your specific example, you want to extract the `src` attribute of the only `iframe` in the document. There are multiple ways to do that. One example is to use `getElementsByTagName` to pull the first `iframe` like this:

```
const src1 = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src;
```

Now that we have the `src` attribute, we can split it apart and process the `url` query value. This is where we will use the `URL` class which comes with NodeJS. According to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html), we can get the search parameters by creating a URL object and accessing the `searchParams` attribute like this:

```
const params = (new URL(src1)).searchParams;
```

Now you've got the query string as a `URLSearchParams` object and you can access individual terms like this:

```
const scURL = params.get('src');
```

If you look at the contents of `scURL` now, you'll find it is the embedded url which was passed as a query, so we can parse that with another `URL` object and extract the `pathname` attribute like this:

```
const src2 = (new URL(src2)).pathname;
```

We're getting close now, and can split the path apart to the get value you wanted using JavaScript's standard string functions:

```
const val = src2.split('/')[2];
```

And print the result:

```
console.log(val);
```

... which produces this output:

```
11111111
```

To summarize, here is the complete code:

```
const jsdom = require('jsdom');
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const data = `<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" 
src="http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F11111111&amp;auto_play=false
&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;color=c3000d&amp;show_comments=false&amp;liking=false
&amp;download=false&amp;show_user=false&amp;show_playcount=false"></iframe>`;

const { document } = (new JSDOM(data)).window;

const src1 = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src;

const params = (new URL(src1)).searchParams;

const scURL = params.get('src');

const src2 = (new URL(src2)).pathname;

const val = src2.split('/')[2];

console.log(val);
```

Feel free to consolidate that and eliminate intermediate values as desired.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a terribly bad idea to parse HTML with a regular expression, but this might be forgivable. I'd look for the complete URL for safety:

```
var pattern = /w\.soundcloud\.com.*tracks%2F(\d+)&/
  , trackID = (html.match(pattern) || [])[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the track id is always 8 digits and the html doesn't change you can do this:

var trackId = html.match(/\d{8}/)

Answer (score 0):

The Right™ way to to do this is to parse the HTML using some [XML parser](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-parsers-xml) and get the URL that way and then use a reg-exp to parse the URL.

If for some reasons you don't have an infinite amount of time and energy, one of the proposed purely reg-exp solutions would work.